# ORA-00904 : invalid identifier Error

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

Oracle 11g Express Edition ..Error while Creating Table

```
  CREATE TABLE FLIGHT_FARE (
  FLIGHT_FARE_ID INTEGER  NOT NULL  ,
  FLIGHTROUTES_FR_ID INTEGER  NOT NULL  ,
  TBLFARE_FARE_ID INTEGER  NOT NULL    ,
  PRIMARY KEY(FLIGHT_FARE_ID)  ,
  INDEX FLIGHT_FARE_FKIndex2(TBLFARE_FARE_ID)  ,
***INDEX FLIGHT_FARE_FKIndex2(FLIGHTROUTES_FR_ID)) // ERROR ON THIS LINE
```

ORA-00904 : invalid identifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `INDEX` syntax you're trying to use is not valid in Oracle (perhaps it is in some other systems).  To create simple indexes like these, use a separate `CREATE INDEX` statement.

You also appear to be trying to create two indexes with the same name.

Comment: Specifically, the word INDEX itself is tagged as the "invalid identifier" at that point in the `create table` statement. Since the Oracle keyword INDEX cannot be used in that place in a `create table` statement, it is interpreted as a column name ("identifier") and, since it is a reserved keyword, it is invalid as a column name.